# Displaying new line from JSON string in Swift

Tags: php, json, string

I have an API that returns JSON. The JSON is generated by PHP. Some data contain new lines in the form of `\n`. When I try to display the data in an iOS `TableViewCell`, the new lines show up as string `\n`. How can I fix that?

[image: PHP that generates the string with new lines:]

[image: Output in table view cell]

Comment: in IOS side you can replace your '\n' wtih whatever you want.

Comment: Removed the swift tag since this should be fixed on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `\n` in double quote.

```
"\n"
```

instead of
`'\n'`

from the backend side.